# Return to natural numbers from a logarithmic difference in python

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, difference, logarithm

I'm working with time series data and have transformed numbers to logarithmic differences with `numpy`.

```
df['dlog']= np.log(df['columnx']).diff()
```

Then I made predictions with that transformation.

How can I return to normal numbers?

Comment: `numpy.log` gives you an array of results, because it is a multi-valued function, there is no one number. However, the numbers in the array are 'normal', except for values that don't have normal number values like `Inf`. Are you looking for a way to get from those values to `float`? In other words, can you provide an example of what you tried, what you got and what you were expecting to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Reversing the transformation shouldn't be necessary, because `columnx` still exists in `df`
- `.diff()` calculates the difference of a Series element compared with another
  element in the Series.

  - The first row of `dlog` is `NaN`.  Without a "base" number (e.g. `np.log(764677)`) there is not a way to step back that transformation

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnx': [np.random.randint(1_000_000) for _ in range(100)]})
df['dlog'] = np.log(df.columnx).diff()
```

#### Output:

```
 columnx      dlog
  764677       NaN
  884574  0.145653
  621005 -0.353767
  408960 -0.417722
  248456 -0.498352
```

### Undo `np.log` with `np.exp`

- Use `np.exp` to transform from a logarithmic to linear scale.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnx': [np.random.randint(1_000_000) for _ in range(100)]})
df['log'] = np.log(df.columnx)
df['linear'] = np.exp(df.log)
```

#### Output:

```
 columnx        log    linear
  412863  12.930871  412863.0
  437565  12.988981  437565.0
  690926  13.445788  690926.0
  198166  12.196860  198166.0
  427894  12.966631  427894.0
```

#### Further Notes:

- Without a reproducible set, it's not possible to offer further solutions

  - You can include some data: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)
  - Include the code used to transform the data: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- Another option is, produce the predictions without taking `np.log`